# Collection View with corner radius in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionview, rounded-corners

I have a CollectionViewController and I would like to set corner radius to the CollectionView (the part below the header view).

[image]

This is what I would like (the corner radius in yellow). Is it possible? Do you have any idea about how I could do that?

Comment: you have plenty of solutions for this on the internet. Try any of those and if you come across any errors we are here to help you.

Comment: you can set clear colour to your collectionview and set corner radius to collectionviewcell..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was quite simple.
I have just removed the inset on the top of the collectionViewLayout and added a new view to the HeaderView.
After that, I applied the corner radius to the view added and it worked :)

Answer (score 2):

```
        extension UICollectionView {
    func roundCorners(_ corners:UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = mask
    }}

   collectioniew.roundCorners([.topLeft,.topRight], radius: 5)
```

Comment: Thank you but your answer doesn't work with a Header View

Comment: Works well. Note - Typo on collectionView name to call function.

Comment: Well, on second look, it provides a mask with radii, but prevents scrolling within the collection view.

Answer (score 0):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    
    cell.viewCell.layer.cornerRadius = 25.0
    cell.viewCell.clipsToBounds = true
    
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).